# Automating Photoshop through ASP.NET or PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, photoshop

I want to start a web project in which:

1. User first signs up.
2. Uploads his desired favorite image to website.
3. Selects which action, filter, plugin or even photo editing feature he wants to be applied to the image and the solution came to my mind is automating Photoshop, I mean user submits his request to the server and server opens up Photoshop and automatically applies the desired operation through Photoshop to the image uploaded by user and saves and returns back the result to the user.

Now the problem is that how can i do so and automate Photoshop through `ASP.NET` or `PHP`.
Any solutions appreciated.

Comment: If you have specific problem, you post your code and we try to help you, you can't expect from us to write code for you.

Comment: No i didn't mean you write code for me,I just want someone to show me the path i should go through as i described in my question and i myself will write my code, I thought here is the right place to ask my question,If i posted in the wrong place please let me know or at least do a favor and tell me where should i ask my question to get proper answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you need to check out is Adobe's licensing on using Photoshop in this fashion.

Once you've addressed any licensing concerns, it would be fairly straightforward to automate.  You need to write the actual photoshop automation part using Adobe's ExtendScript (a flavor of javascript) to do the image manipulation you want.  If you include the line '#target Photoshop' at the top of this script that should take care of making sure Photoshop is automatically launched when you execute your script from ASP.NET or PHP.

Chances are you'll want to pass parameters to your scripts - and the only way I am aware to do this would be to write them to a parameters.xml file in a predefined location so that the script can read them in from there.  I do not think you can supply them directly when you call your script.

You won't have a good way to tell when Adobe is finished with the image.  The best thought I can come up with off the top of my head is to predefine an image drop location and have ASP.NET/PHP poll for the resulting image occasionally.  Depending on what you are doing, and what size images the manipulation could take a significant amount of time - you may want to come up with an alternative solution.

ETA: From .NET you can also automate photoshop more directly via its COM interface.  You'll need to do a bit more research to get it working, but [this link](http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/) should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: When i received 6 negative votes for asking my question,I really got disappointed,But your answer gave me hope again.Thank you very much for your inspiring answer.

Comment: I suspect you'd have gotten less down votes if you targeted your question a bit more.  i.e. How can I get Photoshop to apply a filter to an image from ASP.NET or PHP?  The rest of your project structure/goals isn't really relevant to the question of how to make the two environments work together and makes it look like you just want someone to write the code for you.  But I feel your pain - it is sometimes hard to know what to include and what to leave out.  Why don't you edit your question to improve it for the next person?

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help and suggestion,To tell you the truth,I'm newbie in web development languages, and i'm trying to get hang of using them first and then focus on my main project,I will come back and reask the question in correct format after improving my web programming knowledge.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, using PHP to receive params and talk to photoshop to edit image. Seems C# has more ability to deal with such things and will definitely give it a go.